# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'privateKey') at connectWallet

Tags: javascript, web3js

I am designing an application that I want to connect to the Metamask wallet and receive the private key
But I get the following error in the console
This is my code

```
    <script>
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
async function connectWallet() {
  try {
    await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  
    const privateKey = await web3.eth.accounts.wallet[0].privateKey;
    const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
    const balanceInBnb = web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether');
    console.log(balanceInBnb);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
    </script>
```

I've tried different ways but to no avail. When I manually enter the private key, everything works.